# Add description next to matrix

Tags: matrices

I have the following definition of a standard basis vector:

[image: Definition of standard basis vector]

This text was compiled by the following code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

For $ \mathbb{R}^n $, we let $e_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (the standard basis vector) 
denote the vector with a 1 in the $j$-th entry and 0 elsewhere: 
\[
    e_j = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 (\text{jth spot}) \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
.\] 

\end{document}
```

But I don't like the way the entry marked as the "jth spot" comes out. I would like some way to maybe take that description out and put it next to it outside of the matrix. How could I do this?

Edit: I know that, in this case, it is possible to do this just by writing `j\text{th spot}` right next to the matrix, since the 1 happens to be in the center of the matrix. However, I don't like this solution because it doesn't generalize to other spots in the matrix. What other ways are there to do this?

Comment: Shouldn‘t moving \text after \end{pmatrix} work? Or use a Kronecker notation instead.

Comment: I'd define the matrix as having entries `e_{ji}` with *i* in range [1, *n*] where only `e_{jj}` is 1. This seems like a basic thing the world of mathematics should have an agreed-upon notation for, doesn't it? Your notation I haven't seen. It definitely would make sense to leave the `1` inside and maybe point an arrow towards it with the text. But that's not really a good textbook notation, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the element in a separate `array` to the right of the `pmatrix`. Just add the same number of lines and a closing element to avoid gobbling of the closing `\\` (you'll see `\mathstrut` in my example). For completeness, I've added an "i-th element" label as well, so you can see what that looks like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

For $\mathbb{R}^n$, we let $e_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (the standard basis vector) denote the vector with a~1 in the $j$-th entry and~0 elsewhere: 
\[
  e_j = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
  \end{pmatrix}~
  \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
     \\ \\ (i\text{-th entry}) \\ (j\text{-th entry}) \\ \\ \\ \mathstrut
  \end{array}
\] 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this?

[image]

With `nicematrix` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
    e_j = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col,nullify-dots]
    0       \\ 
    \vdots  \\ 
    0       \\  
    1       &   (j\text{th spot}) \\ 
    0       \\ 
    \vdots  \\ 
    0 
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

For showed result you need to compile this MWE at least three times since `nicematrix` is based on `tikz` package with options  `remember picture` and `overlay`.

**Edit:**
Considered are @egreg comments.

Comment: Why does the code need to be compiled three times?

Comment: @Mailbox It uses Ti*k*Z in the background and positioning extra items requires multiple measuring steps.

Comment: It should be `j\text{th spot}`

Comment: Thanks! One last thing: what do the options `last-col` and `nullify-dots` do?

Comment: @Mailbox,  `nullify-dots` can be removed (since it has no function in temporary solution, it would have if instead of `\vdots` were used `\Vdots`), the `last-col` define "exterior" column, i.e. column after parenthesis. For more details please look in package documentation,